# Hibernate 5.6.12 calls setProprtyValue method for immutable CompositeUserType

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the immutable implementation of CompositUserType.

The `setPropertyValue` method is overriden:

```
@Override
public void setPropertyValue(final Object component, final int property, final Object value)
    throws HibernateException {
  throw new HibernateException("Object is immutable.");
}
```

The `isMutable` methos id overriden as well:

```
@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
  return false;
}
```

Before the version 5.6.12 of Hibernate everything work ok but after the update it looks like `setPropertyValue` methos is being called even though `isMutable` return false.

Does anyone know what was changed and what is the right way to use CompositeUserType with immutable classes in the updated versions?

I tried to have a look at the change log but didn't find any reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following information it looks like it was a bug that was introduced in the version 5.6.11. This bug will be fixed in the 5.6.13 release:
https://in.relation.to/2022/11/03/hibernate-orm-5613/